# Is it possible to create completely separate modules in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to modularize a node js application like namespacing in C# that when I import some namespace I do not have access to its internal members?

For example suppose I have three modules, module A, B, and C. Only module B uses module A export, so I want to package A and B and only export module B export.

If it's not possible, is there any transpiler, library or any other tool that can do it for me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the architecture you are using. Check out Uncle Bob's clean architecture.

Check it out here:
http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

This architecture will allow you to write independent modules and just inject required modules anywhere as dependencies.